# Maven plugin for preprocessing and generating sources

Tags: java, software-development

Does anyone know a maven plugin that can works this way:

1. You can set a phase of execution
2. You can set a list of files by some pattern
3. You can point to some arbitrary class from the dependency of that plugin (the dependency you have set in pom.xml)  - and the class is in charge of processing all that matching files.

There exist `maven-processor-plugin` which is used for annotations and works exactly the way described, but I need something like it only for not processing annotations but rather arbitrary files.

I've seen some specialized plugins - like, say - [antlr4](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/antlr4-maven-plugin) plugin, or, say, - but what about something general?

Also, it would be nice if someone will create a tag - `maven` or `maven-plugin`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've wrote it myself and published at github.
Behold the [Processit Maven Plugin](https://github.com/Schahen/processit-maven-plugin).

Basically you add it as a plugin, add a dependency to this plugin declaration and then just list specific processors that need to be implemented somewhere else.